# using -replace to remove a string with special characters from cells in a csv

Tags: windows, powershell, csv

I have a `CSV` file like:

```
"localpath"
"C:\Users\calabresel"
"C:\Users\goslinep"
"C:\Users\deangelisr"
"C:\Users\bannont"
"C:\Users\goodwind"
```

I am looking for a way to isolate just the username from each field.  I will then query the AD to determine if each user is disabled or enabled.  I haven't been able to figure out how to get just the last piece though.  My idea was to use -replace to replace the identical string with null like this:

```
$txt = import-csv paths1.csv | % {$_.localpath = $_.localpath -replace "C:\Users\", ""}
```

That came back with invalid regular expression pattern errors though which I assumed was a result of the target string containing special characters (the backslashes).  I then started looking for a way to get powershell to take the \ literally instead.  That lead me to try this:

```
$txt = import-csv paths1.csv | % {$_.localpath = $_.localpath -replace [Regex]::Escape("C:\\Users\\"), ""}
```

and this

```
$txt = import-csv paths1.csv | % {$_.localpath = $_.localpath -replace "C:\\Users\\", ""}
```

both of those methods stop the invalid regular expression errors and just return me a fresh line without complaining.  however when I print the `$txt` variable it is empty...

I'm certain I am approaching this problem from the wrong angle and/or with improper syntax but I could use some guidance as I just started working with powershell a week ago.

any help provided would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will import the CSV file and then get the leaf of the path. I.e the user name.

```
$txt = Import-Csv paths1.csv | ForEach-Object { Split-Path $_.localpath -leaf }
```

If you still want to use your replace method, just take out the `$_.localpath =` part and it should work.

```
$txt = Import-Csv C:\@@Scatch\test.csv | % { $_.localpath -replace "C:\\Users\\", ""}
```

Comment: just had a thought...what is the best way to add back in the path once I get the list of username filtered down to only disabled ones?  I will need the full path to match against the get-wmi command...

Comment: @soltkr That would a good thing to ask in a new question. But you have another line to save what you want in a different variable for use later. eg. `$FullPath = Import-Csv C:\@@Scatch\test.csv | Select-Object -ExpandProperty localpath`

Answer (score 2):

The reason why you aren't getting anything back into `$txt` is that you update a property of `$_` but don't return `$_`.

Assuming that you want to use the regex rather than `Split-Path`

```
$txt = import-csv C:\temp\test.csv | % {
    $_.localpath = $_.localpath -replace "C:\\Users\\", ""
    $_
}
```

Or

```
$txt = import-csv C:\temp\test.csv | % {
    $_.localpath -replace "C:\\Users\\", ""
}
```

Comment: thanks for the info, this cleared things up a bit for me

Answer (score 2):

other solution

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\test.txt" | select @{N="Value";E={$_.split('\')[-1].replace('"', '')}} -Skip 1
```